# STM32F0 programming with GCC arm-none-eabi : hardfault in __libc_init_array

Tags: c, gcc, stm32

I'm trying to make a firmware for a STM32L030x6 MCU.

I did a simple code which seems to work on the eval board featuring a STM32L030x8 MCU. By 'seems to work' I mean I am able to reach main fct and toggle gpio.

But when flashing on my target STM32L030x6, I get an hardfault very early in the startup code :

```
Reset_Handler:
  ldr   r0, =_estack
  mov   sp, r0          /* set stack pointer */

/* Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM */
  movs r1, #0
  b LoopCopyDataInit

CopyDataInit:
  ldr r3, =_sidata
  ldr r3, [r3, r1]
  str r3, [r0, r1]
  adds r1, r1, #4

LoopCopyDataInit:
  ldr r0, =_sdata
  ldr r3, =_edata
  adds r2, r0, r1
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc CopyDataInit
  ldr r2, =_sbss
  b LoopFillZerobss
/* Zero fill the bss segment. */
FillZerobss:
  movs r3, #0
  str  r3, [r2]
  adds r2, r2, #4


LoopFillZerobss:
  ldr r3, = _ebss
  cmp r2, r3
  bcc FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
    bl  SystemInit
/* Call static constructors */
    bl __libc_init_array <-------------- after a breakpoint here, typing "ni" in gdb hardaulft
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
  bl main <----------------------------- never reach here

LoopForever:
    b LoopForever
```

Since flash sizes are different I changed the linker script accordingly, so the memory initialization must be fine.

I am not sure what the "__libc_init_array" do, its part of libc (newlib-nano in my case).

One interesting thing is, if I comment the call to "__libc_init_array", it still runs fine on eval board and still hardfaults on my target. So maybe the issue is prior the call.

I am quite confident with SystemInit, since it is a template of ST, which handle both MCUs.

It is probably not an hardware problem, since, using Keil, I am able to successfully flash my target and run simple app code.

Any idea on what can be the problem ? So insight on this call to the libc ?

Thanks a lot by advance

Comment: HardFault. Search for undefined behavior, out-of bound access, stack overflow and so on. `__libc_init_array` takes of running all the contructors in c++ code, in C code it has just one empty function if I remember correctly. But you can add custom function to be run before main by the __libc_init_array using `__attribute__((__constructor__))`. Try to debug code in step mode instruction by instruction, compile with `-ggdb -g3` and `-O0` and see where the hardfault happens.

Comment: what is your stack pointer set to on each system and how big is the sram on each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since flash sizes are different I changed the linker script
>   accordingly

I bet that you did not change the stack initial address (and probably RAM size as well) in the vector table so the first call causes the HF.

BTW gdb command line in 21st century? Waste of time and extremely inconvenient. Install Atollic Studio - it is free and it is supported by the STM (actually STM is the owner of the company). Easy to create projects.

If you are going to do it manually it will be the way of the stress and frustration.